# convert synchronous python function into asynchronous one

Tags: python, asynchronous

I have a synchronous function that does HTTP call to some remote endpoint

```
class ZipCodeService(Service):
    def zip_code_check(self, payload, threaded=False):
        response = self.post(client=self.get_client(), data=payload, threaded=threaded)
        return ZipCodeCheckResponse(response.output())
```

I call this function inside the asynchronous function like this

```
async def lookup_zipcode_available_speed(self, request_body=None):
    response = self.zip_code_service.zip_code_check(payload={
        "zip_code": request_body.get("zip_code"),
        "house_number": request_body.get("house_number")
    })
    return ZipCodeCheckOutputSerializer().dump(response)
```

It works. However I want to turn that synchronous function into the asynchronous one. The `post` method that I use in `ZipCodeService` is provided by `Service` class that I have no control over.

How to make it asynchronous? As far as I understand I can only achieve that by some decorators that would put the function into event loop with `loop.run_in_executor`?

Edit:

So far I have come up with this. Not sure if it is works or not as for some reason debug does not enter wrapper function

```
import asyncio
from functools import partial, wraps

def to_async(func):
    @wraps(func)
    async def wrapper(*args, loop=None, **kwargs):
        if loop is None:
            loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        pfunc = partial(func, *args, **kwargs)
        return await loop.run_in_executor(None, pfunc)
    return wrapper
```

Comment: You can also put the function into the event loop with `loop.run_in_executor` without decorators.

Comment: but for that I should either provide `loop` as async function paramter or I need to get `asyncio.get_event_loop` all the time? The thing is that I have a lot of functions like this, so probably decorator is better.

Comment: Well then use a decorator. But the answer to your question "do I have to use a decorator" is "no".

Comment: @mkrieger1 do I need to add `await` to my function call (when I use wrapper) or it will work fine without it due to `get_event_loop`?

Comment: You need to use `await`, the point of using `run_in_executor` is to get something back which you can `await`.

Comment: @mkrieger1 the thing is when I use the decorator like in the my question - I have updated it - it fails with `object dict can't be used in 'await' expression`